# React setState inside useEffect async

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am attempting to perform a series of Axios requests inside the `useEffect()` of a react component. I am aware that these requests are asynchronous, and I should maintain a piece of "loading" state that specifies if series of requests have been completed.

```
    const [state, updateState] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        let innerstate = []

        allRespData.map(single_response => {
            axios.post("<URL>", {
                raw_narrative: single_response[index].response
            })
            .then((response) => {
                innerstate.push(response.data)
            }); 
        })  
        updateState(innerstate)
        setLoading(false)
    }, []);

    if (loading)
        return (<h3>  Loading </h3>)
    else {
        console.log(state)
        return (<h3> Done </h3>)
    }
```

I would expect the output from the  above code to be a list containing the data of each response. Unfortunately, I think that data only arrives midway through the `console.log()` statement, as initially an empty list `[]` is logged, however the list is expandable- therein my expected content is visible.

I am having a hard time doing anything with my `state` at the top, because the list length is constantly 0, even if the response has already loaded (loading == false).

[image]

How can I assert that `state` has been updated? I assume the problem is that the loading variable only ensures that a call to  the `updateState()` has been made, and does not ensure that the state has actually been updated immediately thereafter. How can I ensure that my `state` contains a list of response data so that I can continue doing operations on the response data, for example, `state.forEach()`.

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-from-json-placeholder-forked-dcqdps?file=/src/index.js][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not awaiting any of the requests, so `updateState` will get called before any of the responses have had time to come back. You'll be setting the state as `[]` every time. You also need to `return` your `axios.post` or the data won't get passed to `.then`

There are lot of nicer ways to handle this (I'd recommend looking at the [react-query library](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/), for example). However, to make this work as it is, you could just use `Promise.all()`. Something like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all(
    allRespData.map(single_response =>
      axios
        .post('<URL>', { raw_narrative: single_response[index].response })
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => {
          // A single error occurred
          console.error(error);
          // you can throw the error here if you want Promise.all to fail (or just remove this catch)
        })
    )
  )
    // `then` will only be called when all promises are resolved
    .then(responses => updateState(responses))
    // add a `.catch` if you want to handle errors
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);
```

Comment: This worked,  I appreciate the insight you've provided! I will read the 'react-query' docs attached. Thanks again